# Router subscribe in child router

Tags: typescript, angular

How to fire some events on every URL changes in child router?
I can implement to fire events on URL changes in root router like the below code, but I cannot in child router.

I'm using router-deprecated and Angular2 beta, not RC.

```
// myapp.component.ts
@RouteConfig([
  {
    useAsDefault: true,
    name: 'Main',
    path: '/...',
    component: MainComponent,
  },
])
export class MyAppComponent {
  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    _router.subscribe((url: string): void => {
      // Fire on every URL change
      // e.g. URL "/" to "/sub1", "/sub1" to "/sub2"
    });
  }
}

// main.component.ts
// URL: /
@RouteConfig([
  {
    useAsDefault: true,
    name: 'Sub1',
    path: '/sub1',
    component: Sub1Component,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sub2',
    path: '/sub2',
    component: Sub2Component,
  },
])
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private _router: Router) {
    _router.subscribe((url: string): void => {
      // Does not fire...
    });
  }
}

// sub1.component.ts
// URL: /sub1
export class Sub1Component {}

// sub2.component.ts
// URL: /sub2
export class Sub2Component {}
```

(Of course, I omitted `import` syntax and Decorators in the above.)

Comment: why can't you do the same in child ? do you get an error ?

Comment: do by using `router.location()` and perform action according to url changes.

Comment: Try to use _router.parent.subscribe in your child component

Comment: I could get expected to using `_router.parent.subscribe` ! Thanks @yuzuri and others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get expected to using `_router.parent.subscribe` !
Thanks @yuzuri.